# Could not load type 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin.DataRefresh.ViewDataRefreshHistory'

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

Has anyone seen or solved this error message:

> Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin.DataRefresh.ViewDataRefreshHistory'?

it occurs when I click Manage PowerPivot Data Refresh from a document library, specifically on a spreadsheet.

If I reboot sharepoint, the problem goes away, but eventually returns - usually the next day. perhaps some errant process is interfering with sharepoint, but I certainly at a loss to what it might be.

uls is not very helpful.

sharepoint 2013 sp1 farm enterprise self hosted

Comment: could you please check the ULS for complete trace, why you are getting this error.

Comment: this is the high level error: much the same as I reported:

Getting Error Message for Exception System.Web.HttpParseException (0x80004005): Could not load type 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin.DataRefresh.ViewDataRefreshHistory'. ---> System.Web.HttpParseException (0x80004005): Could not load type 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin.DataRefresh.ViewDataRefreshHistory'. ---> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load type 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin.DataRefresh.ViewDataRefreshHistory'.  

this message will not allow posting the full trace

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Central Admin and click on System Settings.  Then click on Manage Farm Solutions.  Look at the powerpivotwebapplicationsolution.wsp file by clicking on it. Make sure that the website urls don't have port numbers.  You will probably have to retract your solution and then re-deploy it.

Answer (score 0):

Re-Deploying the solution fixed the issue. I my case Central Admin URL with port was there, after redeployment, I was able to see both central Admin and WebApp (Without port number) URL's in Deployed to field.